# Incorrect values for await page.$$('.')).length

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

wanted to keep scrolling down, until all the elements with a particular classname are loaded in a dynamic HTML environment.

This is the code i used:

```
while ( (await page.$$('.xj7')).length < counter) { 
    await page.evaluate( () => 
         window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight));
 }
```

The problem is that after it loads all the elements, it doesn't stop scrolling. I don't know why is that, as it should exit the while loop.

I decided to test the value of the `page.$$('.xj7')).length`

I wrote this test code:

```
while ( (await page.$$('.xj7')).length < counter) { 
   const read = (await page.$$('.xj7')).length;
   console.log(read);
   await page.evaluate( () => 
      window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight));
}
```

The values increased from 12, to 24, then they got stuck at 30! Then when the page has loaded all the elements, the value dropped to 28! I should note the page has hundreds of these elements loaded!

That's why it stucks to this loop. I don't understand while the page has hundreds of these elements, it ranged to these values.

Comment: The problem is specific to your case and cannot be solved without replicating it. I guess you can trust the value because it just counts querySelectorAll nodes. You could try to put a delay inside the loop because it spams the window.

Comment: How can i trust when ther;s like 500 of thele elements loaded but the counter never exceeds 30? Not only that, it goes down too!

Comment: This likely means that at that moment something happens on the page that you don't expect.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Can you share the target URL to check for that strange script behaviour?

Comment: Hi! When i ran console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.xj7').length); at the console at the target webpage, i got a varying number of  these elements. Which means that as the webpage loads new elements (via the user scrolls down), it also deletes the old ones. So it was not a puppeteer issue! Thank you for your interest!